# Web Capability Analysis Tool (WCAT) - No Output XML

Tags: iis-7, asp.net, load-testing

I have WCAT 6.3 running fine up until the point where it is supposed to generate the log.xml file.  In the cmd window, I just see the last Cooldown update, like so:

```
******************************************************************************
COOLDOWN 20/30 secs                             0 hours, 2 minutes, 20 seconds
******************************************************************************
         Connections =                        0 (                       0/sec)
         Disconnects =                        0 (                       0/sec)
        Socket Sends =                        0 (                       0/sec)
     Socket Receives =                        0 (                       0/sec)
     Full Handshakes =                        0 (                       0/sec)
Reconnect Handshakes =                        0 (                       0/sec)
          Bytes Sent =                        0 (                       0/sec)
      Bytes Received =                        0 (                       0/sec)
    Bytes Sent (SSL) =                        0 (                       0/sec)
Bytes Received (SSL) =                        0 (                       0/sec)
  Time To First Byte =                        0 (                     Minimum)
  Time To First Byte =                        0 (                     Maximum)
  Time To First Byte =                        0 (                     Average)
   Time To Last Byte =                        0 (                     Minimum)
   Time To Last Byte =                        0 (                     Maximum)
   Time To Last Byte =                        0 (                     Average)
        Transactions =                        0 (                       0/sec)
     Normal Requests =                        0 (                       0/sec)
     Secure Requests =                        0 (                       0/sec)
    Normal Responses =                        0 (                       0/sec)
    Secure Responses =                        0 (                       0/sec)
        Total Errors =                        0 (                       0/sec)
      Connect Errors =                        0 (                       0/sec)
         Send Errors =                        0 (                       0/sec)
      Receive Errors =                        0 (                       0/sec)
      Parsing Errors =                        0 (                       0/sec)
   Unexpected Status =                        0 (                       0/sec)
```

In my client.ubr file, I have the following:

```
scenario
{
    name    = "default_doc";

    warmup      = 30;
    duration    = 90;
    cooldown    = 30;

    default
    {
        setheader
        {
            name    = "Connection";
            value   = "keep-alive";
        }
        setheader
        {
            name    = "Accept";
            value   = "image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, application/vnd.ms-excel, */*";
        }
        setheader
        {
            name    = "Accept-Language";
            value   = "en-us";
        }
        setheader
        {
            name    = "User-Agent";
            value   = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0";
        }
        setheader
        {
            name    = "Accept-Encoding";
            value   = "gzip, deflate";
        }
        setheader
        {
            name    = "Host";
            value   = server();
        }
        version     = HTTP11;
        statuscode  = 200;
        close       = ka;
    }

    transaction
    {
        id      = "default_doc";
        weight  = 100;

        request
        {
            url = "/home.aspx";
        }
    }
}
```

And in my settings.ubr file I have this:

```
settings
{
      server         = "test.company.com";
      clients        = 1;
      virtualclients = 2;

    counters
    {
        interval = 10;

        counter = "Processor(_Total)\\% Processor Time";
        counter = "Processor(_Total)\\% Privileged Time";
        counter = "Processor(_Total)\\% User Time";
        counter = "Processor(_Total)\\Interrupts/sec";

        counter = "Memory\\Available KBytes";

        counter = "Process(w3wp)\\Working Set";

        counter = "System\\Context Switches/sec";
        counter = "System\\System Calls/sec";

        counter = "Web Service(_Total)\\Bytes Received/sec" ; 
        counter = "Web Service(_Total)\\Bytes Sent/sec" ; 
        counter = "Web Service(_Total)\\Connection Attempts/sec" ; 
        counter = "Web Service(_Total)\\Get Requests/sec" ; 
    }

    registry
    {
        path = "System\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\FileSystem";
        name = "NtfsDisableLastAccessUpdate";
        type = REG_DWORD;
    }

    registry
    {
        path = "System\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\Tcpip\\Parameters";
        name = "SynAttackProtect";
        type = REG_DWORD;
    }
}
```

The test runs fine when I run the following command on the controller:
    `wcctl -f settings.ubr -t client.ubr`
and the following on the client:
    `wcclient`

Just not sure why it wouldn't spit out the log.xml file or give me any kind of message/error as to why it didn't.  The CPU remains utilized at roughly 50% until I finally kill it (I've given it up to 30 minutes waiting on it to do something).  Anything I'm missing here or suggestions you might have?

**Edit**
Yes, I have also tried the -o switch with no luck... same results either way.

Comment: Have you tried adding the output option to the wcctl command line? (-o logfile.xml)

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure this is not the answer you are looking for, but the log file is not being produced because you are killing the process before it completes.  We should figure out why the process doesn't complete on its own.

I've come close to reproducing your scenario by selecting some text in the wcat client window, which appears to cause the communication between wcat client and wcat controller to become fouled up and never* complete.

Can you check to see that no one is stalling either the wcat client or controller (by selecting text in the console window or other means)?

thanks,
mark

*never defined to be 20 minutes for testing purposes